# Imported packages do not auto-install

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I have a private package stored locally (and version-controlled via SVN).  To install the package, I am asking the user to SVN-update his/her package directory, then `setwd()` on the directory, and then `devtools::install()`.

This package imports many CRAN packages, which are not stored locally.  These imported packages are not auto-installing during the installation, which produces the error message `Dependency package foo not available`.  The user must manually install `install.packages('foo')`, then try again, only to get `Dependency package bar not available`, ad nauseam, even though `foo` and `bar` are among my `Imports:`

**Details:**

My DESCRIPTION file looks like:

```
Package: apackage
Type: Package
Title: Package to Do Stuff
Version: 1.11111
Date: 2017-03-02
Author: C8H10N4O2
Maintainer: C8H10N4O2<C8H10N4O2@example.com>
Description: Package that does many useful things
License: file LICENSE
Depends:
    R (>= 3.3.0)
Imports:
    bit64 (>= 0.9.5),
    data.table (>= 1.9.6), 
    extrafont (>= 0.17),
    foreach(>= 1.4.3),
    ggplot2 (>= 2.0.0),
    gbm (>= 2.1),
    grid (>= 3.2.3),
    gridExtra (>= 2.0.0),
    httr (>= 1.1.0),
    readxl (>= 0.1.1),
    scales (>= 0.4.0),
    xlsx (>= 0.5.7)
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
Suggests: testthat (>= 0.9.1)
```

But upon invoking `check()` or `load_all()` I still get the error:

```
Error in (function (dep_name, dep_ver = NA, dep_compare = NA)  : 
  Dependency package gridExtra not available.
```

And then my user has to `install.packages('gridExtra')`, and then he/she gets another dependency not available error.

**What I have tried:**

According to [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html):

> `Imports:` packages listed here must be present for your package to
>   work. In fact, any time your package is installed, **those packages
>   will, if not already present, be installed** on your computer
>   (devtools::load_all() also checks that the packages are installed).

I also checked [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies) but couldn't find anything else on this topic.

Am I correct that these packages **should** be auto-installing, and what should I do to ensure that they auto-install?

I recognize that the problem is not fully reproducible, but I can't link to my repo, so I'm happy to provide any additional details.

```
**versions**
R 3.4.0, platform = x86_64-w64-mingw32
devtools 1.13.1
```

Comment: Did you set up your own repository with a private package on it? Does your repository also contain the dependencies for the package? Normally `install.packages('foo')` would install from CRAN but you seem to be doing something else here. How exactly did you have the user configure their R workspace to make that work?

Comment: @MrFlick yes I am using my own SVN repository for my package. It does not contain the packages I am importing.  I will update the question.  Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 2):

You are reinventing packaging with R. I advise against.  You could just [drat](https://cran.r-project.org/package=drat) to create a repository. This is tried and true *and works*.

And this *deployment* aspect, for both *production of local packages* as well as their *use and installation* is entirely orthogonal to where you keep sources.  Don't mistake a source code repository for code distribution mechanism.

In sum, using [drat](https://cran.r-project.org/package=drat) locally along with local GitHub Enterprise instance has worked swimmingly for us at work, and [drat](https://cran.r-project.org/package=drat) in general is in fairly widespread use.

(Usual disclaimers as I am the one who started [drat](https://cran.r-project.org/package=drat), but I had the good fortune of a bunch of contributors too.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, even though it doesn't really answer my immediate question. I'm not at all familiar with drat.  Other than the dependency issue, updating the package directory from SVN and building from there works really well for our small team.  The diffs make it extremely easy to understand what has changed between commits.  Can you elaborate by what you mean "don't mistake a source code repository for code distribution mechanism?

Comment: Yes, I have answered that before; see the four vignettes on drat as well as other questions here.  In brief, only `install.packages()` pulls dependencies for you. Installating from SVN "works" for various definition of working but is inferior.  Almost all experienced R users agree: use packages, and using package repositories is a corollary.

Comment: C8H10N4O2, did you figure it out? I have same problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel  I feel that this has been a recurring problem that is either unaddressed or undocumented or I am missing the point. I understood Imports as a way to install all the dependencies to your package directly from CRAN. The error "Dependency package bar not available" doesn't say much but it sure doesn't mean that the package is not available on CRAN.  Therefore, the user would just have to install all the missing packages? Sounds a little bit wrong

Comment: @JustinThong You need a better example / maybe a fresh question.  Eg if I start on a fresh system (say a Docker container) and request `RcppArmadillo` from CRAN, _of course_ I also get `Rcpp` which it depends upon / `Imports` / `LinkingTo`.  That is not dependent on the form: any one of `Depends`, `Imports`, `LinkingTo` does it as documented.

Comment: @dirkeddelbuettel Yes. Probably wise to try new install in docker container. I am excited to know what environ and global settings which cause this to occur. thx anyway

Comment: Okay. I think after some searching. It has become clear that Imports in DESCRIPTION file only builds any dependencies if your package is already on CRAN. If it is not already on CRAN, any locally working project should install dependencies manually via install.packages. I wonder whether there is a reason for this? This situation is counter-intuitive to usual NPM installs.